# RegExp.test for HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, string

I'd like to determine if a string contains a substring not enclosed by "<>". For example,

`<image src=abc> -> false`

`<image src=abc><image src=def> -> false`

`<tag>hello</tag> -> true`

`<image src=abc>hello -> true`

I know I can do the following:
`!_.isEmpty(String(input).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, ''))`, but wondering if there's a better way, using regex.test

Answer (score 1):

Turn the HTML string into a document, then take the document's `.textContent`, trim it, and see if it's empty:

```js
const hasContent = str => new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body.textContent.trim() !== '';

console.log(hasContent('<image src=abc><image src=def>'));
console.log(hasContent('<tag>hello</tag>'));
```

Don't use a regex when you can parse the DOM.